# Colorblind: Change Excel parentheses color in formula bar?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, accessibility

Does anyone know of a way to change the color of parentheses in the Excel formula bar (in macOS)?

To make formulas more legible, cell ranges and parentheses are color coded in Excel. I'd guess the colors are red, blue, purple and maybe green? But I'm colorblind, and not really sure.

And that's the main thrust of it – the color coding doesn't help a lot because I'm colorblind, and the chosen colors don't have much contrast.

Is there a way to change these colors to be more accessible?

Comment: Could there be an accessibility option in the OS? Within Excel, the only potential solution that I could think of is using the `=LET()` function on all your complicated formulas. It's supposed to help readability. Of course you'll have to rewrite all of your formulas...

Comment: I dont think what you want is possible. But to be honest the colours dont really work for me either and I am not colour blind :) Those little bold flashes of the matching parentheses while moving your cursor is more valuable. Mostly I just hit enter and hope Excel figures out where the missing parentheses should go.